# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined while trying to list FormArray of FormGroups in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I've got an items that can be modified according to client needs. To take a list of Items with different modifications I've decided to create a form where they can add as many items as they want and choose specifications for each of them. For that I need to create a FormArray of FormGroups. Everything compiles as it has to be, but I've got an error when the program tries to render the form: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Here is code of my app.component.ts (items and addItem())

```
import {FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      companyName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      items: new FormArray([])
    })
    this.addItem()
  }

  submit() {
    if(this.form.valid){
      console.log('Form submited', this.form)
      const formData = {...this.form.value}

      console.log('Form Data: ', formData)
    }
  }

  controlSelectChanged() {
    if(this.form.get('item').get('controlSelect').value == 'Ручное'){

    }
  }

  addItem() {
    const item = new FormGroup({
      modelSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      quantity: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      width: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      height: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      colorSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      factorySelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      articleSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      articleSelect2: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      controlSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      controlSideSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      controlFactorySelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      controlAcceptorSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      automaticFactorySelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      quantityPult: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      automaticAdditionSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      notes: new FormControl(''),
    });
    (this.form.get('items') as FormArray).push(item)
    console.log(this.form.get('items'))
  }
}
```

and here is a fragment of code that renders this Array from app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <div class="form-group invis">
          <label for="inputCompanyName">Название вашей компании</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputCompanyName" formControlName="companyName" aria-describedby="companyNameHelp" placeholder="Введите название компании">
          <small id="companyNameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Это поле обязательно для заполнения.</small>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-20" [disabled]="form.controls['companyName'].invalid">Далее</button>
        </div>

<div *ngFor="let item of form.get('items')" class="form-group">
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="item">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="modelSelect">Модель</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="modelSelect" formControlName="modelSelect">
                <option>ASN130</option>
                <option>ASN</option>
                <option>ASN110 cab</option>
                <option>ASN 110 GPZ TENS</option>
                <option>Зашивка на люверсах</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
              <label for="quantity">Кол-во</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="-" formControlName="quantity">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
              <label for="width">Ширина</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="width" placeholder="-" formControlName="width">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
              <label for="height">Высота</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="height" placeholder="-" formControlName="height">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="colorSelect">Цвет профилей</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="colorSelect" formControlName="colorSelect">
                <option>9003 Белый</option>
                <option>9004 Черный</option>
                <option>8017 Коричневый</option>
                <option>7024 Антрацит</option>
                <option>1024 Бежевый</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="factorySelect">Производитель тента</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="factorySelect" formControlName="factorySelect">
                <option>COPACO</option>
                <option>DICKSON</option>
                <option>М8</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="articleSelect">Артикул тента</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="articleSelect" formControlName="articleSelect">
                <option>COPACO</option>
                <option>DICKSON</option>
                <option>М8</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="articleSelect2">Сторона</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="articleSelect2" formControlName="articleSelect2">
                <option>Back со стороны короба</option>
                <option>Front со стороны короба</option>
                <option>Back со стороны подворота</option>
                <option>Front со стороны подворота</option>
              </select>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="controlSelect">Управление</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="controlSelect" formControlName="controlSelect" (change)="controlSelectChanged()">
                <option>Ручное</option>
                <option>Автоматическое</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="controlSideSelect">Сторона управления </label>
              <select class="form-control" id="controlSideSelect" formControlName="controlSideSelect">
                <option>Справа</option>
                <option>Слева</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="controlFactorySelect">Производитель привода</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="controlFactorySelect" formControlName="controlFactorySelect">
                <option>Дорхан</option>
                <option>Somfy</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="controlAcceptorSelect">Вид привода</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="controlAcceptorSelect" formControlName="controlAcceptorSelect">
                <option>Без приемника</option>
                <option>Cо встроенным приемником </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="automaticFactorySelect">Производитель автоматики</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="automaticFactorySelect" formControlName="automaticFactorySelect">
                <option>Дорхан</option>
                <option>Somfy</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <label for="quantityPult">Кол-во пультов</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantityPult" placeholder="-" formControlName="quantityPult">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <label for="automaticAdditionSelect">Дополнительная автоматика</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="automaticAdditionSelect" formControlName="automaticAdditionSelect">
                <option>Нет</option>
                <option>Датчик ветра</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <label for="notes">Примечания</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="notes" rows="3" formControlName="notes"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
<div class="form-row justify-content-md-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-30 addNewItemButton" (click)="addItem()">Добавить новый товар</button>
        </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-20" [disabled]="form.controls['item'].invalid">Далее</button>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-20" [disabled]="form.invalid">submit</button>
      </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've missed out the crucial bits of the HTML. Could you add the HTML hierarchy between the `<form>` and the form array.

Comment: Code is updated

Comment: `form.controls['item'].invalid` - are you sure `controls['item']` is defined?

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is no error anymore, but the thing is form is still not rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obnxyi

1. I refector the component using the `formBuilder` to have a cleaner code.
2. In the `*NgFor` the proper way to access controls of a `FormArray` is using `form.get('items').controls` with `controls` that give you the access to the array of controls
3. I moved the loop into the `ng-container` in order to set the `formArrayName` property inside the parent of the repeated tag. So you now have `<div formArrayName="items" class="form-group">`

Comment: src/app/app.component.html:24:34 - error TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

24         <div *ngFor="let item of form.get('items').controls; let idx = index" class="form-group">
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

after adding .controls it shows this error

Comment: Did you fully follow the example on stackblitz? I changed the  build on the form using a `FormBuilder`

Comment: Yes, I'm.
But the problem was that for some reason I can't use .controls, but it works with ['controls'], so it should look like: form.get('items')['controls']

Answer (score 0):

Your form HTML should mirror the structure of your form.

So if you build the following form:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    companyName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    items: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        modelSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      }),
      new FormGroup({
        modelSelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      })
    ])
  });
}

onSubmit() {
  const models = this.form.get('items')
    .controls
    .map(x => x.get('modelSelect').value);
  console.log(models);
}
```

Then the minimum HTML you need is this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input formControlName="companyName" />
  <div formArrayName="items">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let control of form.get('items').controls; index as i">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="modelSelect" />
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

Notice how the form directives mirror the structure of the `FormGroup`. You bind the items of a `FormArray` using `[formGroupName]="i"` if your array is made up of form groups.